# Access Denied for external API from Heroku / AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku

I'm developing an application that trying to use an unofficial HomeDepot API, the app is deployed to Heroku.

When running it locally it works well, but from the Heroku server, I occasionally get an Access Denied error from HomeDepot.

Example:

```
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.homedepot.com/..." on this server.
Reference #18.8c9ec817.1613321797.55cbcde
```

I know that HomeDepot is blocking access from certain locations, mostly APAC, but my Heroku server is located in the US - I have looked up for the server IP and it is actually AWS, dynamically changing but always US.

Has anyone else experience the same on Heroku/AWS and can share some tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Expect major sites to take action against scraping.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [Akamai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPhxY.png) (CDN provider) 403 error, like ceejayoz said, you were likely blocked for scraping or excessive requests.

Your best bet is to contact Amazon for a new IP address as this one no longer works on Akamai protected sites.